# Which vhost was pointed by ip addres when bind two or more vhost to one ip?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

The configuration bind two domain name

```
www1.example.com
www2.example.org
```

to the one ip address `172.20.30.40`.

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@www1.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/vhosts/www1"
    ServerName www1.example.com
    ErrorLog "/www/logs/www1/error_log"
    CustomLog "/www/logs/www1/access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@www2.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/www/vhosts/www2"
    ServerName www2.example.org
    ErrorLog "/www/logs/www2/error_log"
    CustomLog "/www/logs/www2/access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My puzzle is :what if i type `172.20.30.50:80` ,which domain's webpage will show by apache?
`www1.example.com`  or  `www1.example.com`  ?

Comment: Solve your own puzzle: `wget -O- http://172.20.30.50/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apache's [Name-based Virtual Host Support](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) documentation:

> Name-based virtual host resolution only chooses the most appropriate name-based virtual host after narrowing down the candidates to the best IP-based match. […]
>
> When a request arrives, the server will find the best (most specific) matching  argument based on the IP address and port used by the request. […]
>
> #### The default name-based vhost for an IP and port combination
>
> If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then **the first listed virtual host** that matches that will be used.